# RoR: how can I add columns to my database on my live heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

I am trying to add :price, :location, and :product to the columns for my microposts table. I have already done a bunch of other migrations and I have heard that rolling back all of migrations and redoing them is error prone. So I guess the other option is the schema file? I have heard that the schema file is just to be read and not edited. I have been looking at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html but can't find the right info. They briefly talk about change_table which I think could be useful but it doesn't go into depth. Is this what I am looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new standalone migration:

```
rails g migration add_price_location_and_product_to_microposts
```

It will create a file in the `db/migrate` folder, edit it:

```
def change
    add_column :microposts, :price, :float # dont forget to change the type to the columns
    add_column :microposts, :location, :string
    add_column :microposts, :product, :integer
end
```

(You can define the `change` method, instead of `up` and `down` because `add_column` is a reversible command.)

And then, run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: but Im not exactly sure how. Is there a something I enter on the command line? should I edit the schema file. Where should that code go and how do I execute it?

Comment: I edited my answer. You should never touch schema.db, never ;)